# Go: strconv.Atoi() retorna 0

Tags: string, go, números-enteros

Hola estoy empezando con GO. Mi problema es el siguiente:

En la funcion getData hago una entrada de datos, en el cual el usuario digita un número. El problema es que este dato lo intento convertir a entero con la función Atoi de la libreria strconv, y el resultado de este siempre es 0, cuando debería ser el numero digitado en la entrada, que es de tipo de dato string.

Desde ya, gracias por su tiempo!

````
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

// type operator interface {
//  suma() float64
//  multiplicacion() float64
// }

// type add struct {
// }

func getData(reader *bufio.Reader) (int, error) {

    // Ejemplo: Aqui coloco un numero. En este caso, por ejemplo: 4
    fmt.Print("Digite la cantidad de numeros: ")
    number, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(number) // Aqui el resultado es 4, con tipo de dato STRING

    // AQUI EL PROBLEMA

    numberInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(number) // "Pasando de tipo de dato STRING A INT "
    fmt.Println(numberInt)               // Aqui me retorna 0, con tipo de dato INT

    // Mi intencion es que la variable "numberInt" retorne
    // lo mismo que el resultado de la entrada "number"

    return numberInt, err
}
func numbers(amountNumbers int, reader *bufio.Reader) []float64 {
    var numbersList []float64

    for i := 0; i < amountNumbers; i++ {
        fmt.Print("Digite un numero: ")
        num, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        numFloat, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(num, 64)
        numbersList = append(numbersList, numFloat)
    }

    return numbersList
}

func main() {

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    amountNumbers, err := getData(reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    numbersList := numbers(amountNumbers, reader)

    fmt.Println(numbersList)

} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es con `ReadString()`, según la [documentación](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader.ReadString):

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
> returning a string containing the data up to and including the
> delimiter.

Lo que nos dice que el valor ingresado incluye el `\n`, lo cual finalmente hace que siempre el valor de `number` no sea adecuado para `Atoi`. Lo que eventualmente puedes hacer es un "trim" para quitar espacios (y adicionalmente el caracter de fin de línea)

```
numberInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimSpace(number))
```

O bien usar directamente [`fmt.Scan()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scan) para leer directamente un entero:

```
func getData(reader *bufio.Reader) (int, error) {

    fmt.Print("Digite la cantidad de numeros: ")
    var numberInt int
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&numberInt)

    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(" Error al leer el entero: ", err)
      return 0, err
    }

    fmt.Println(numberInt)               // Aqui me retorna 
    return numberInt, err
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio!